# Acessar Device Wifi do Aparelho Android

Tags: android, apache-cordova

Estou trabalhando com o Phonegap e me surgiu a necessidade de atraves de um link na minha app acessar as configurações de wifi do meu aparelho.

Alguém tem alguma idéia ai?

Comment: Acessar as configurações para leitura e edição? Ou Você quer apenas chamar as configurações? Qual o objetivo de acessar o wifi do dispositivo? Além de verificar se está usando wi-fi ou rede de dados.

Comment: Veja se não tem o que você procura aqui http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html

Comment: Obrigado, eu estou fazendo um app no phonegap e quando o sistema reconhecer que o usuário ta sem internet ele vai exibir uma opção aonde o usuário iria clicar e ir para as configurações do wifi diretamente para acessar, ainda não consegui :/